# R: select where condition LIKE (grep)

Tags: r, substring, sql-like

I am working with R.

I have the following data:

```
library(fastLink)
a = data.frame(dfA)

head(a)

  firstname middlename        lastname housenum          streetname          city birthyear
1    daniel     joseph          secuya     1564         fairview ct       Oakland      1957
2     david     marion      motakabbir     6909  shepherd ave apt 4       Oakland      1971
3    joseph      aaron          joseph     4547        piedmont ave Castro Valley      1948
4    joseph      clyde         mcnulty    30436            49th ave Castro Valley      1961
5 akensheye     nguyen paniagua chavez     6967         glenwood dr       Oakland      1972
6      john       <NA>          bozman     6363            nabor st     Livermore      1951
```

From here, I am trying to select rows from this table where the column "firstname" contains the letters "jo". I tried to do this with the "grep" command:

```
a[grep("jo", a$firstname)] 

Error in `[.data.frame`(a, grep("jo", a$firstname)) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

Does anyone know why this error is appearing?

Thanks

Comment: Data frame subsetting syntax is `df[rows, cols]`. You're missing a comma :)

Comment: @heds1: thank you for your reply! But I thought I added the comma? a[grep("jo", a$firstname)]

Comment: Try `a[grep("jo", firstname),]`

Comment: @PeaceWang: thank you for your reply! unfortunately, this doesnt work :  aa = a[grep("jo", firstname),]
Error in grep("jo", firstname) : object 'firstname' not found

Answer (score 0):

```
final = a[grep("cl", a$firstname),]
```

This seems to have fixed it! thanks everyone!